# how to programatically pause a gae taskqueue from python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

The basic idea is:

```
import google
default_queue = google.appengine.api.taskqueue.Queue()
default_queue.pause()  # there seems to be no function to do this
do_some_stuff()
default_queue.unpause() # or this
```

So how can I pause and unpause the task queue?

Comment: Why do you want to pause a taskqueue programmatically? What is your high level goal?

Comment: My high level goal is very much to do with business objects that have no place on stackoverflow. There is a pause button on the google cloud console taskqueue gui because some of the nice people at google recognize that it can be useful to temporarily stop processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a pull queue and my own worker that I can pause and unpause